# How do I insert attributes for users/accounts with MeteorJS?

Tags: meteor

I would like to insert attributes to users. If it were another collection I would add a method to a collection. How can I accomplish this with users since it is already built in with Meteor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd add a method just like you would for any other collection - just use `Meteor.users` as the instance. For example:

**server**

```js
Meteor.methods({
  'users.cats.add: function() {
    Meteor.users.update(this.userId, {$inc: {cats: 1}});
  }
});
```

**client**

```js
Meteor.call('users.cats.add');
```

You'll find this example particularly useful of your users happen to have cats.

Comment: I had been placing Meteor.methods in the collection files: lib/collections/exampleCollection.js. Where would a meteor method go for users?

Comment: Yeah that's fine - I didn't mean to imply that the method could only be defined on the server - it can also be placed in a shared dir like `lib`. You also get the benefit of [latency compensation](https://meteorhacks.com/introduction-to-latency-compensation) that way.

Comment: So where would I place it? I haven't defined the users collection since it comes packaged with meteor. I don't know where to put it?

Comment: `lib/collections/users.js` sounds like a reasonable choice - just don't redefine the collection there - have the file only contain methods.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to call:

```
Meteor.users.update({ _id: myUserId }, { $set: {
  someAttribute: 'someValue'
}});
```

Note that this code will only work server-side. If you want to add those attributes as soon as each new account is created then `Accounts.onCreateUser` would be a good place to do that. Look here:

http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_oncreateuser

for more details.